# How do I get optparse list all possible arguments and options?

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I'm using Python 2.6.2 (unfortunately can't upgrade to 2.7, or I'd use argparse). How can I get optparse to return a list of the options that have been added via 'add_option'?

Here's some sample code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('--one')
parser.add_option('--two')
(opts,args) = parser.parser_args()

optlist = parser.funcToGetListOfOptions()
print optlist
['one', 'two']
```

I've looked through the optparse source and can figure it out by accessing internal attributes, but that doesn't seem very kosher. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> parser._get_all_options()[1:]
[<Option at 0xb7d185ec: --one>, <Option at 0xb7d1866c: --two>]
>>> [x.get_opt_string() for x in parser._get_all_options()[1:]]
['--one', '--two']
>>> [x.dest for x in parser._get_all_options()[1:]]
['one', 'two']
```

Comment: Thanks, F.J. I guess since optparse is not being developed any more, it's safe enough to access attributes that are named to indicate they are _private.

Answer (score 1):

I got a great hint from [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary), using ast.literal_eval, which I've never used before. With that, and calling **str** directly from the options in `(options, args) = parser.parse_args`, you'll get what you want quite quickly.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(options.__str__())
{'one': None, 'two': None}
>>> ast.literal_eval(options.__str__()).keys()
['one', 'two']
```

This is a lot more portable then using private methods, and you get to use a whole new module.